# NameError: name 'beam' is not defined

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

in get_csv_reader NameError: name 'beam' is not defined [while running 'Flatten the CSV-ptransform-73']

I am trying to read a CSV on apache beam and load it to BQ. I used the first line in the CSV (headers) to convert all the rows into a dictionary before loading it to BQ.

below is my pipeline code

```
#pipeline
def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()



    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_table",
        help="Output BigQuery table for results specified as: "
             "PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE or DATASET.TABLE.",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_file",
        help="file location of input data "
             '"GCS path"',
    )

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    input_file = known_args.input_file
    output_table = known_args.output_table


    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    # headers = ['id', '_title12764THE_', 'type', 'description', 'release_year', 'age_certification', 'runtime', 'genres', 'production_countries', 'seasons', 'imdb_id', 'imdb_score', 'imdb_votes', 'tmdb_popularity', 'tmdb_score']
    headers= read_headers(input_file)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    # Create Pipeline (PCollections)
        parsed_csv = (p | 'Create from CSV' >> beam.Create([input_file]))
        flattened_file = (parsed_csv | 'Flatten the CSV' >> beam.FlatMap(get_csv_reader))
        convert = flattened_file | "bq convert" >> beam.Map(lambda x: parse_csv(x,headers))
        convert | 'Write to bq' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            output_table,
            schema='SCHEMA_AUTODETECT',
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
```

Method to read the headers:

```
#reading headers
def read_headers(csv_file):
  fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='hidden-mapper-351214')
  with fs.open(csv_file,'r') as f:
    header_line = f.readline().strip()
  headers = next(csv.reader([header_line]))

  # BQ Column name requirements

  BQ_headers=[]
  for head in headers:
      BQ_headers.append(re.sub('\W+', '', head.lstrip('0123456789')))

  return BQ_headers
```

Method to read CSV into P-collection:

```
def get_csv_reader(readable_file):

    # Open a channel to read the file from GCS
    gcs_file = beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open(readable_file)

    # Read file as a CSV
    gcs_reader = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(gcs_file))

    # next(gcs_reader)

    return gcs_reader
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
File "/home/akhil_kakumanu/ingest-demo/ingest-csv.py", line 32, in get_csv_reader
NameError: name 'beam' is not defined [while running 'Flatten the CSV-ptransform-73']
```

my line 32 is this

```
gcs_file = beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open(readable_file)
```

My code was initially working fine when I hard-coded the headers in a list. But when I use GCSFS, it started throwing that error. I think it has to do something with opening the same file with two different libraries but not sure. I have installed beam SDK and GCSFS too. Like, I said it worked fine when I hardcoded the headers.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening and how to get around this? Also, if there is any other effective way to read any CSV and push it to BQ please suggest it.

Comment: Have you defined your functions (including `get_csv_reader`) inside your pipeline?

Comment: I am not sure what that means but my code was working fine without using GCSFS. was getting output in BQ. Anyways, I included my whole pipeline code now. Let me know if I am missing something there

Comment: Not sure how it could be connected with that, but try defining your functions after the line `with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:`, basically inside the `with` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try adding

```
import apache_beam as beam
```

inside function `def get_csv_reader`?

The issue of a NameError is usually that the worker doesn't know about values from global namespace. See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors.

Comment: it worked when I put all these imports : import apache_beam as beam, import io,    import csv and also I had to define the parse_csv() function within the pipeline. how can they access other functions and not parse_csv(). Not sure why the workers are suddenly not able to access the global space. it worked fine earlier and even now if I hardcode the headers instead of gcsfs. any idea?

Comment: Dataflow optimizes your pipeline into different stages when running it. It's possible that the new beam I/O introduced in your get_csv_reader changes how the pipeline is shaped and executed on workers, thus different context/global namespace. When you hard code the headers, they are pickled as part of the function definition/transform, without introducing new I/O or changing the shape of the pipeline. That's why it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question. Do you know if the way I am reading CSV files is efficient? will this method fail for huge files? I ask because I am using csv.reader in my method. I feel like this loads the file into memory causing a failure for huge files. Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you are fine since you just read the first line in your code to extract the headers. Neither open() nor readline() loads the whole file into the memory.